# Join on two columns, if null then only join on one

Tags: sql, performance

I have the following two tables:

customers:

| customer_id | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1234 |
| bbbb | 3456 |

status:

| department_id | customer_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | NULL | silver |
| 3456 | bbbb | gold |
| 1234 | bbbb | gold |

I want to join status on customers, but if if it returns NULL I want to give the customer the department default. My ideal Output for this would be the following:

| customer_id | department_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1234 | silver |
| bbbb | 3456 | gold |

I have tried to do two left joins, but am getting a memory usage error. Is there another way to do this that is efficient?

Comment: Can you post the problematic code with the two left joins? In principle I would expect that to work.

Comment: I know you said you're using left joins, but a memory usage error suggests an accidental [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join), which can produce a lot of rows depending on the size of the tables. Could you post your current query?

Comment: What database? I can do this with a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause, but syntax for that looks a little different depending on what you're using.

Comment: Two left outer joins sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
select c.*, coalesce(s.status, d.status) as status
from customers c
left join status d on d.department_id = c.department_id 
                  and d.customer_id is null
left join status s on s.department_id = c.department_id 
                  and s.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 status
        FROM status s
        WHERE s.customer_id = c.customer_id
           OR (c.customer_id IS NULL AND s.department_id = c.department_id)
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.customer_id is NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
     ) as status
FROM customers c
```

The kicker is what kind of database you're using. If it's MySql you might want LIMIT 1 instead of TOP 1. For Oracle you'd look at the ROWNUM field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is always a match at least on the `department_id`, you need an `INNER` join and `FIRST_VALUE()` window function will pick the proper `status`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.customer_id,
       c.department_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(s.status) OVER (
         PARTITION BY c.customer_id, c.department_id
         ORDER BY CASE 
                    WHEN s.customer_id = c.customer_id THEN 1 
                    WHEN s.customer_id IS NULL THEN 2 
                    ELSE 3 
                  END 
       ) status
FROM customers c INNER JOIN status s
ON s.department_id = c.department_id;
```

Depending on the database that you use the code may be simplified.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf1bee5b129e1ac3a4d271ce9be8036b).